# How to parse a string into int

Tags: pointers, go, bytebuffer

I am trying to execute git commands through Go code. I need to convert `*byte.buffer` value string to int.

```
cmd := exec.Command("git", "cat-file", "-s", dir+":"filename)
var outBuf bytes.Buffer
var stderr = bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stferr = &stderr
err := cmd.Run()

filesize, _ := strconv.Atoi(out.String())
fmt.Println("filesize..", filesize) //return 0
fmt.Println("filesize..", out.String()) // returns 345
```

I want to convert `out.String()` value to string which is type `*byte.buffer`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Hey sngo, have a look at the Atoi error. Maybe you get an invalid syntax error?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> filesize, _ := strconv.Atoi(out.String())
> ```

You are ignoring the error return.  Don't do that.

If you print the returned error, you will see that `git cat-file -s <path>` produced the string `"345\n"` (or possibly `"345\r\n"`).  That is, there's a newline (or CRLF) at the end of the number.  That is prohibited:

```
filesize = 0, err = strconv.Atoi: parsing "345\n": invalid syntax
```

Remove the newline and `strconv.Atoi` will be fine with the value.  Consider, e.g., applying `strings.TrimSpace()` to the string.  (See [Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/ugs86YF_Zxm)).